How to join table with lastest value from time series table
I have two tables in postgres.
CREATE TABLE data (
    name VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE timeseries (
    name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES data(name),
    time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    value INTEGER NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (name, time)
);

How I can join timeseries table to data table in such way I'll get value column with latest timestamp

Why do you (think you need) a join to data?  Is SELECT name, MAX(time) as time, MAX(value) as value FROM timeseries GROUP BY name not enough ?

@Luuk Well, max(value) is not necessarily the latest.

@Stefanov.sm; NO? Why does this dbfiddle throw error?: https://dbfiddle.uk/nR8yHa-S

@Luuk as the error message says, because value is not aggregated

@Stefanov.sm: I misread your comment... (sorry)

You can extract the latest records of timeseries table per name into a CTE using distinct on with custom order by and then join with data table (supposing that it has more columns and the above is just an illustration).
with t as 
(
 select distinct on (name) *
 from timeseries order by name, time desc
)
select * -- your expression list here
from t join data using (name);

Or if you do not need extra data table attributes then simply
select distinct on (name) *
from timeseries order by name, time desc



The subquery does find the max value, and then you can select it:
SELECT *
FROM timeseries
WHERE (name,time) IN (
   SELECT t1.name,max(t1.time)
   FROM timeseries t1
   GROUP BY name);

see: DBFIDDLE

The basic technique for this kind of tasks - use CTE with ROW_NUMBER window function:
WITH d AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time DESC) rn
    FROM timeseries
) SELECT * FROM d WHERE rn = 1;

Within CTE we get all rows numbered according their timestamp in DESC order, so last row get row number = 1, after that we filter result of CTE for rows with number 1
Test the solution here
